# Embedding PDF files within HTML/ Problem with unwanted mousewheel movement

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, embed

Does anyone out there embed PDF files for browser viewing?

I am using embedded PDF files as a way to easily display reports through a browser (FireFox).  The actual PDF is about 10 pages long, but the HTML page is coded with the embed tag and uses the Open Parameters to display just a few aspects of the PDF, in an easy to read format.  The annoying part is that the embedded PDF sections can accidentally be scrolled with the mousewheel, which ruins the look of the report in the browser.  Is there a way to disable this?

The html has about 16 different divs, all with embed tags within, pointing to separate sections of the same pdf document using the open parameters... here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>


<head>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="2000">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="db.css" />


<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.addEventListener){ /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */
    document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', stopWheel, false);
} 
function stopWheel(e){
    if(e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */
}
</script>

</head>


<body id="pdf">

<div id="mid" onMouseOver="stopWheel(e);"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=1&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=100,135,400" width="900" height="325"/></div>
<div id="l1"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,134,105" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l2"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,484,105" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l3"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,835,105" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l4"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,134,233" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l5"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,484,233" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l6"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,835,233" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l7"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,134,361" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l8"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,484,361" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l9"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,835,361" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l10"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,134,489" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l11"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,484,489" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l12"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,835,489" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l13"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,134,617" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l14"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,484,617" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l15"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,835,617" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l16"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,134,745" width="119" height="83"/></div>
<div id="l17"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=5&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=75,484,745" width="119" height="83"/></div>


</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the first div, i was trying to use javascript to disable the mouse wheel, which did not work.  Is there a possible javascript, html, css or maybe even another solution to stop unwanted mousewheel scrolling within an embedded pdf document?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function scroll(){
   return false;
}
document.onmousewheel = scroll;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems now that div with the updated javascript does not display.       `<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.addEventListener){ /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */
    document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', stopWheel, false);
}
 
function scroll(){
   return false;}


}
</script>
</head>
<body id="pdf">



<div id="mid" document.onmousewheel = "scroll();"><embed src="run_rate_original_test.pdf#page=1&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&zoom=100,135,400" width="900" height="325"/></div>`  I am a bit rusty on javascript, it might be my error.

Comment: any other suggestions out there?

Comment: do it like this = document.onmousewheel=scroll . That's it

Comment: would you be able to give a more specific example of the syntax.  it does not effect the pdfs